# Is it possible to get 15fps by using movenet on celeron N4020?

Tags: tensorflow.js, movenet

now I am using tensorflow.js + movenet for real-time workout pose estimation.
I plan to use these codes on intel celeron N4020 (1.1GHz) that I did not buy yet.

is it possible to get over 15fps on this very low level of CPU ?
is there any reference or document to check this ?

thank you.